# im having a runtime error for tic tac toe as i didn't use any functions in this program please once look at the code

Tags: python, runtime-error, tic-tac-toe

i'm getting an error while running this code
i alredy did this using functions but this time i thought of doing it without functions
but there is some kind of error
i dont even know that we can do this tic tac toe like this

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import random
print('WELCOME TO TIC TAC TOE\n')
board= [' '] * 10
player2 = ' '
player_1 = None
player_2 = None
turn = player_1
clear_output()
print('     |   |  ')
print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
print('     |   |  ')
print('---------------')
print('     |   |  ')
print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
print('     |   |  ')
print('---------------')
print('     |   |  ')
print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
print('     |   |  ')
marker = ''
while not (marker == 'X' or marker == 'O'):
    marker = input('player 1 do you want to be X or O\n').upper()
    
    if marker == "X":
        player1 = "X"
        player2 = "O"
    else:
        player1 = "O"
        player2 = "X"
      
if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
    print('player 1 will go first')
    turn=player_1
else:
    print('player 2 will go first')
    turn=player_2
    
win_check = False
if ((board[7]==player1 and board[8]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #horizontal check
           (board[4]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[6]==player1) or #horizontal check
           (board[1]==player1 and board[2]==player1 and board[3]==player1) or #horizontal check
           (board[1]==player1 and board[4]==player1 and board[7]==player1) or #vertical check
           (board[2]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[8]==player1) or #vertical check
           (board[3]==player1 and board[6]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #vertical check
           (board[1]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #diagonal check
           (board[3]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[7]==player1)):
    win_check=True
elif ((board[7]==player2 and board[8]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #horizontal check
           (board[4]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[6]==player2) or #horizontal check
           (board[1]==player2 and board[2]==player2 and board[3]==player2) or #horizontal check
           (board[1]==player2 and board[4]==player2 and board[7]==player2) or #vertical check
           (board[2]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[8]==player2) or #vertical check
           (board[3]==player2 and board[6]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #vertical check
           (board[1]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #diagonal check
           (board[3]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[7]==player2)):
    win_check=False
    
board_check = True
for i in range(1,10):
        if board[i] == ' ':
            board_check = True
        else:
            board_check = False
position = 0
gameon = True
while gameon == True:
    if turn == player_1:
        while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not board[i] == ' ':
            position = int(input("Enter the position (1-9)"))
            board[position] = player1
            if win_check == True:
                print("player1 WON!!")
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('---------------')
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('---------------')
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
                print('     |   |  ')              

                gameon = False
                break
            else:
                if board_check == False:
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('---------------')
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('---------------')
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('game is Draw')
                else:
                    turn = player_2
                    
    else:
         while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or  not board[i] == ' ':
            position = int(input("Enter the position (1-9)"))
            board[position] = player2
            print("player2 WON!!")
            print('     |   |  ')
            print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
            print('     |   |  ')
            print('---------------')
            print('     |   |  ')
            print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
            print('     |   |  ')
            print('---------------')
            print('     |   |  ')
            print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
            print('     |   |  ')
            if win_check == True:
                print("player2 WON!!")
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('---------------')
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('---------------')
                print('     |   |  ')
                print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
                print('     |   |  ')
                gameon = False
            else:
                if board_check == False:
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[7]+' | '+board[8]+' | '+board[9])
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('---------------')
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[4]+' | '+board[5]+' | '+board[6])
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('---------------')
                    print('     |   |  ')
                    print('   '+board[1]+' | '+board[2]+' | '+board[3])
                    print('     |   |  ')

                    print('game is Draw')
                else:
                    turn = player_1

        
    replay = input('Do you wnt to play again? Y or N').lower()
    if replay == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

if you could help it will be very usefull for me as im a beginner
in python programing
in this code i cannot get out of while loop and it dosent show any result

Comment: Add the error traceback to the question.

Comment: Your code that checks for a win is before anyone plays, it's not in the loop. The loop that sets `board_check` overwrites the value each time through the loop, so it's just the value from `board[9]`. `while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not board[i] == ' '` should use `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `win_check` and `board_check` should be functions so you can recheck the status at each turn.

Try this code:

```
def win_check():
    if ((board[7]==player1 and board[8]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #horizontal check
               (board[4]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[6]==player1) or #horizontal check
               (board[1]==player1 and board[2]==player1 and board[3]==player1) or #horizontal check
               (board[1]==player1 and board[4]==player1 and board[7]==player1) or #vertical check
               (board[2]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[8]==player1) or #vertical check
               (board[3]==player1 and board[6]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #vertical check
               (board[1]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[9]==player1) or #diagonal check
               (board[3]==player1 and board[5]==player1 and board[7]==player1)):
        return True
    elif ((board[7]==player2 and board[8]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #horizontal check
               (board[4]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[6]==player2) or #horizontal check
               (board[1]==player2 and board[2]==player2 and board[3]==player2) or #horizontal check
               (board[1]==player2 and board[4]==player2 and board[7]==player2) or #vertical check
               (board[2]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[8]==player2) or #vertical check
               (board[3]==player2 and board[6]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #vertical check
               (board[1]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[9]==player2) or #diagonal check
               (board[3]==player2 and board[5]==player2 and board[7]==player2)):
        return False
    
def board_check():
   for i in range(1,10):
        if board[i] == ' ':
            return True
        return False
```

In the game loop, refer to these as functions:

```
if win_check() .......
if board_check() .......
```